# Multiple JSON feed display in HTML table

Tags: javascript, json

I would like to display multiple JSON feed in a HTML table.
With one source my code is working well. But how can I load multiple feed to my table?

Also I would like to know where can I insert  tags to have table header after generate the table?!

My code:

```
<body>
<section>
    <h1>Big Flower profit calculator</h1>
      
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var proxy = "https://api.allorigins.win/get?url=";
                var MyURL1 = "https://whattomine.com/coins/151.json?hr=505.0&p=1800.0&fee=0.0&cost=0.12&hcost=0.0&span_br=1h&span_d=24";
                var MyURL2 = "https://whattomine.com/coins/321.json?hr=2100.0&p=430.0&fee=0.0&cost=0.12&hcost=0.0&span_br=1h&span_d=24";
                var MyURL3 = "https://whattomine.com/coins/334.json?hr=3200.0&p=410.0&fee=0.0&cost=0.12&hcost=0.0&span_br=&span_d=24";
                var MyURL4 = "https://whattomine.com/coins/164.json?hr=350.0&p=324.0&fee=0.0&cost=0.12&hcost=0.0&span_br=&span_d=24";
                let list = [];
                var res = '';
                var table = $("<table id=DynamicTable border=1></table>").appendTo("#ResultArea");

                // FETCHING DATA FROM JSON FILE
                $.getJSON(proxy + MyURL1,
                        function (data) {
                            console.log(data);
                            
                            var adat = data.contents;
                            console.log(adat);
                    // CONVERT JSON
                    res = JSON.parse(data.contents)
                    list.push(res);
                    console.log(list);
                                                                                        
                    $.each(list, function (i, value) {

                    //Create new row for each record
                    var row = $("<tr></tr>").appendTo(table);
                    $("<td></td>").text(value.tag).appendTo(row);
                    $("<td></td>").text(value.difficulty).appendTo(row);
                    $("<td></td>").text(value.difficulty24).appendTo(row);
                    $("<td></td>").text(value.revenue).appendTo(row);
                    $("<td></td>").text(value.cost).appendTo(row);
                    $("<td></td>").text(value.profit).appendTo(row);
                    });


                    });

                });
        </script>
</section>
<div id="ResultArea"></div>
```